# generate event for a button in footerView of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, onclicklistener

I have created a custom ListView with checkbox and textview on each row.i have a button which is placed in footer position of ListView  which is generated programmatically like this

getListView().addFooterView(submit);//submit is name of submit button
    setListAdapter(adapt); //name of adapter
my activity does not have a layout page.
i dont know how to provide click listener event for button. i have searched a lot,but could nt find anything.thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All `View`s can have a click listener set with `View.setOnClickListener()`.

E.g.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         // TODO - do the action.
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx nmw for your generous mind..,but,its not working.if i use the above code,i think it will be applicable to all clicks of that listView.i need click event for that button only

Comment: You're adding a `Button` named `submit` to the footer right? So why would `submit.setOnClickListener()` override all clicks on the `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

Add Button Submit in your xml file:-

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/submit" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Submit" 
</Button>
```

Add this code:-

```
  Button submit;
  submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sumit);
  submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
  {
  public void onClick (View  v) 
  {
  methodname();
  }});
```